# CentOS 7 ssh connection

Tags: centos7

I installed a fresh CentOS 7 but I have trouble with the SSH connection. SSHD is running but I can not connect to it. I have to stop firewalld everytime before I can connect. The strange thing is that I can see the ssh service in the firewalld config. Also the interface is assigned to the public zone. What is wrong?

```
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=none
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=stable-privacy
NAME=eth0
UUID=777a05dc-b7cd-4811-af9c-99644287beab
DEVICE=eth0
ONBOOT=yes
DNS1=192.168.x.x
ZONE=public
IPADDR=192.168.x.xxx
PREFIX=32
GATEWAY=192.168.x.x
IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes


public
target: default
icmp-block-inversion: no
interfaces:
sources:
services: dhcpv6-client ssh
ports:
protocols:
masquerade: no
forward-ports:
sourceports:
icmp-blocks:
rich rules:
```

Comment: what are `firewall-cmd --get-default-zone`, `firewall-cmd --get-active-zones`, `firewall-cmd --list-all` output?

Comment: firewall-cmd --get-default-zone -> public
firewall-cmd --get-active-zones -> public interfaces: eth0
firewall-cmd --list-all -> public
target: default
icmp-block-inversion: no
interfaces:
sources:
services: dhcpv6-client ssh
ports:
protocols:
masquerade: no
forward-ports:
sourceports:
icmp-blocks:
rich rules:

Answer (score 0):

Please set `interfaces: eth0` in configuration file.

Comment: I added the Interface eth0 to the configuration and restarted the Firewalld Service but this did not fix the Problem.

Comment: Could you review the result `firewall-cmd --list-all-zones | less` for `block`, `drop` or other zone specify to bloc
k SSH.

Comment: I double checked the Network Settings and found the root of the issue - the Network mask was misconfigured. Thanks for your help.